# Laravel Eloquent query get users from another model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have another table called tableb and it has a user relationship defined through the user_id field.

I want to run a query against tableb where a certain date is within a certain range but then I want to grab the user table associated with that row but I only want it to grab the user if it's not been grabbed yet. I'm trying to do this all in 1 DB query. I have most of it done, but I'm having trouble with the unique part of it.

Here's what I have right now:

```
    $tableB = TableB::select('users.*')
    ->join('users', 'tableb.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('tableb.start_date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->get();
```

So right now I have 3 entries in tableB from the same user, and ideally I'd like to only get 1 entry for that user.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Add `groupBy('users.id')`. :)

Comment: would you mind adding an example on sqlfiddle.com with example data  and also please add your model files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're selecting only users data, just add a `groupBy` clause in your query.

```
$tableB = TableB::select('users.*')
    ->join('users', 'tableb.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('tableb.start_date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just add `groupBy` like this :

```
$tableB = TableB::select('users.*')
    ->join('users', 'tableb.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('tableb.start_date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
App/user.php

public function getrelation(){      
      return $this->hasMany('App\tableB', 'user_id');
}
```

In Your Controller

```
Controller.php

use App/user;

public funtion filterByDate(user $user)
{
    $date = '2016-02-01';
    $result = $user->WhereHas('getrelation', function ($query) use($date) {
                                    $query->whereDate('tableb.start_date', '>', $date)
                                          ->first();
                        });    
}
```